# How can i make class member to Json serializable

Tags: python, json, discord.py

this is my code

```
with open('setting1.json',mode='r',encoding='utf8')as jfile:
    jdata = json.load(jfile)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def data(ctx):
    a1=[]
    author=ctx.message.author
    a1.append(author)

    jdata["a1"]=a1

    with open('setting1.json',mode='w',encoding='utf8')as jfile:
        json.dump(jdata,jfile)
```

i want to save member data in json ,and i run the code:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Member' is not JSON serializable
```

how can i fix it(or just impossible)?thanks

Comment: The problem is discord.py is returning a Member type object instead of a string and json can't have a 'Member' object, so you need to fix this by turning 'author' to a string

Answer (score 0):

The error says "TypeError: Object of **type 'Member'** is not JSON serializable" It looks like discord.py is returning a type of 'Member' instead of a type of string. To fix this simply turn the variable 'author' to string by turning the line that says `author = ctx.message.author` to `author = str(ctx.message.author)`. That's all you need to do to fix that error. But thought I'd re-do you command so here.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def data(ctx):
    author = str(ctx.message.author)

    with open('setting1.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as jfile:
        if (jfile): loaded = json.load(jfile) # If they's something in this file (Should be a list in this case) then load the data as variable 'loaded'
        else: loaded = [] # But if it's empty then assign a list to the 'loaded' variable

        if (author not in loaded): # Thought you may need this. Checks if the user's name is already there, If it's not then it'll add it, but if it is then it won't add it
            loaded.append(author) # Append to the data we loaded or the list we created
            with open('setting1.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as jfile: # Open the file again this time in write mode
                json.dump(loaded, jfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True) # Dump to the file and done.
```